# Angular Service Worker - Check update immediately

Tags: angular, service-worker

I have setup a service worker in our Angular Project and part of this we have setup the serviceworker  to check for updates when the angular project has changed. The issue is we are having is if there is an update it takes the service work about 2-3mins to detect the update when the app is loaded. How can we change this so that it checks the update immediately when the app is loaded?

Currently our code is as follows. We have service called update.service that has a contructor to check if the service worker is enabled and has the function to init check for update.

```
constructor(private updates: SwUpdate) {     
    console.log('UpdateService','constructor()','Check Service Worker Active',null);
    if (!this.updates.isEnabled) {
      console.log('UpdateService','constructor()','Service Worker Disabled',null);
    } else {
      console.log('UpdateService','constructor()','Service Worker Enabled',null);
    }
           
  }
  /*
  ** name: Init Check Update
  ** desc: Update check on init app - DOESN"T WORK
  */
  initCheckForUpdate(): void {
    // check update on init in prod mode only
    if (this.updates.isEnabled) {
      this.updates.available.subscribe(event => {
        //console.log('Event', event);
        console.log('Current version is', event.current);
        console.log('Available version is', event.available);  
        this.updates.activateUpdate().then(() => {
          alert('There is a new version of the app. Press OK to autoupdate.');
          document.location.reload();
        });
      });
    }
  }
```

Then in the first page that is loaded we have in the ngOnInit()

```
this.updateService.initCheckForUpdate();
```

Appreciate the help it seems a number of people have asked the question in various forums but I am yet to see to an answer.